# Don't get complete set of custom/standard fields in sandbox just after creating it with permission to all objects

Tags: custom-field, sandbox, fields

I just create sandbox in Enterprise Edition but don't get full/complete set of fields for Opportunity.I made a copy from production org.
 Any assistance will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Hi Umer, can you be a little more specific about what issue you're seeing? If your sandbox copy did not complete correctly, you'll need to contact Salesforce for assistance or refresh it again.

Comment: I just bought Enterprise edition license and created a sandbox. I see there are many fields missing in sandbox from opportunity object. I made sandbox for development as production org did't allow me to edit/save code in developer console.

Comment: Thanks @DavidReed for your input. I have created another sandbox and it's working fine. Probably it as an issue from salesforce.